# iMac login screen is very slow (Mojave, maybe the Fusion Drive?)

Tags: imac, fusion-drive, login-screen

Whenever I wake up my iMac, the login screen takes very long time to respond (roughly 8 seconds). This happens on Mojave (I cannot remember if it also happened in the previous OS but I think it did).

I emphasize that it does not happen on my MacBook Pro which is the same OS Mojave. Therefore I think it's an iMac issue.

What can fix this issue?

Comment: It the Mac connected to a fileserver of any kind, or a directory service like Apple's Open Directory or Microsoft's Active Directory?

Answer (score 1):

Is the iMac an older model with a hard disk instead of an SSD? It takes a while for hard drives to 'spin up' compared to an SSD in a newer MacBook Pro.

Comment: The iMac is quite new and powerful. Much more than the MacBook I mentioned in the question.

Comment: iMacs aren't sold with SSD's by default, they are an optional upgrade.   Laptops however are nearly always sold with an SSD by default.

Comment: The iMac actually has HDD. So maybe this is the problem. But still the waiting time for the login seems excessive.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already try resetting the [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) and the [NVRAM (PRAM)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) on your device.

Next try booting into [safe mode (safe boot)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) and then try to restart the Mac afterwards and see if that helps.

> Safe mode (sometimes called safe boot) is a way to start up your Mac
>   so that it performs certain checks and prevents some software from
>   automatically loading or opening. Starting your Mac in safe mode does
>   the following:
>
> - Verifies your startup disk and attempts to repair directory issues, if needed loads only required kernel extensions
> - Prevents startup items and login items from opening automatically
> - Disables user-installed fonts
> - Deletes font caches, kernel cache, and other system cache files

Perhaps [reinstalling macOS via macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) can help.

Also depending on your model and year of iMac, you may be able to upgrade the amount of memory in it and possibly double the current amount.

Comment: The iMac is quite new and powerful. Much more than the MacBook I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the SMC and the NVRAM (PRAM) already? If so what about safe mode (safe boot)?

Comment: I haven't tried these. I will. About the memory, I have 32GB RAM (compared to 8 GB I have in my MacBook Pro), so I don't think that's an issue.

Comment: I agree, especially when you told me its newer. Try safe mode as well, I've updated my answer if you need references.

Comment: I have tried to reset both the SMC and the NVRAM. They didn't help. I did not try the safe mode because I didn't want cache stuff to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

A definitive answer isn't possible with the information provided, but your question showed up in my search for answers to a [*similar issue*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/446755/imac-mojave-suddenly-became-extremely-slow-on-login). I spent some time researching my issue; your issue *sounds similar*, so here's my answer:

#### Answer:

You mentioned in a comment that your iMac vintage is ca. 2019. If that's the case, it's very likely that your iMac was equipped with a [***Fusion Drive***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_Drive). As it turns out, Apple decided to prioritize their profit margins over the service life of the products they manufactured and sold. The result is that all models of Mac hardware equipped with a Fusion Drive are *ticking time bombs*; Apple's design decisions virtually guarantee your iMac will die an early death.

But you shouldn't take my word for that - you should do your own research. I freely admit that I am a strong skeptic of Apple's **current** business practices; in fact, I have come to despise these practices. I am biased. However, I was also trained as an Electrical Engineer, so I still try to discount that bias when attempting to solve problems. In this case, I relied upon the following for this answer:

1. My *general knowledge* of the [wearout mechanism in flash drives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling)<sup>([search refs 1](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=wearout+mechanism+in+flash+drives&t=ffab&atb=v278-1&ia=web))</sup>,
2. Numerous opinions I found online<sup>([search refs 2](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Issues+with+Apple+Fusion+Drive&t=ffab&atb=v278-1&ia=web))</sup>,
3. Analysis [from this source in particular](https://eclecticlight.co/2016/06/03/how-long-will-the-ssd-in-my-fusion-drive-last/) due to the author's objective analysis.
4. Diagnostics produced by the [DriveDx](https://binaryfruit.com/drivedx) drive diagnostic tool.

I will further opine that Apple should have recommended DriveDx to all customers with Fusion Drives as their own Drive Utility is worthless for diagnosing the SSD component of a Fusion Drive. Apple must have been aware of the design issues, and their failure to provide any remediation or early warning to customers shows lack of *good faith*, and even negligence. Equally reprehensible is the fact that Apple now refuses to repair these defectively-designed Fusion Drives once your machine reaches a certain age.

Again: You needn't rely on my *opinions*; you may review my sources, or find your own.

#### In Closing:

I'm posting this answer 3+ years after the question was originally posted, and it seems likely that it may not be of much help to the OP at this time. However, I have no doubt that others have experienced, and will continue to experience premature failures; Apple didn't discontinue use of Fusion Drives in *all products* until November 2021.

I was motivated to [post a question here based on my experience with the Fusion Drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/446755/imac-mojave-suddenly-became-extremely-slow-on-login). I feel I learned something from the experience - including some repair options that may keep your Apple hardware out of the local landfill. Please see the answer(s) for details.