# late 2014 iMac crashing when going to screen saver or sleep

Tags: imac, sleep-wake, crash, kernel-panic

I have been coming back to may computer several times today and finding that it has crashed and restarted.  below is a copy of the report.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I am running big sur (11.7.2)

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80051c1596): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8007c8131c, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000878, CR3: 0x000000000912b000, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffffa0a5263d48, RCX: 0xffffff86ae71f740, RDX: 0x0000007544f20000
RSP: 0xffffffa0a5263d40, RBP: 0xffffffa0a5263df0, RSI: 0xffffff9370a5e600, RDI: 0xffffff9370a9ad20
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0xffffffa0a5263d98, R10: 0xffffffa07dfb66dc, R11: 0xffffff86a4d37540
R12: 0xffffff9370a9ad20, R13: 0xffffffa0a5263d40, R14: 0xffffff9370a5e600, R15: 0x0000000000000000
RFL: 0x0000000000010203, RIP: 0xffffff8007c8131c, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000878, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2, PL: 0, VF: 1

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa0a5263760 : 0xffffff800508821d 
0xffffffa0a52637b0 : 0xffffff80051d0bd3 
0xffffffa0a52637f0 : 0xffffff80051c11ca 
0xffffffa0a5263840 : 0xffffff800502ca2f 
0xffffffa0a5263860 : 0xffffff8005087a3d 
0xffffffa0a5263980 : 0xffffff8005087d33 
0xffffffa0a52639f0 : 0xffffff800589bc8a 
0xffffffa0a5263a60 : 0xffffff80051c1596 
0xffffffa0a5263be0 : 0xffffff80051c127d 
0xffffffa0a5263c30 : 0xffffff800502ca2f 
0xffffffa0a5263c50 : 0xffffff8007c8131c 
0xffffffa0a5263df0 : 0xffffff800670fa6d 
0xffffffa0a5263e80 : 0xffffff80050ce935 
0xffffffa0a5263ef0 : 0xffffff80050cf8a4 
0xffffffa0a5263fa0 : 0xffffff800502c13e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[52C6EB14-CA4E-3209-BDD3-60092E16E6A4]@0xffffff8007c70000->0xffffff8007c81fff
         com.apple.driver.AppleRAID(5.1)[4D1AD965-09EB-315F-AF7C-3187E64791EF]@0xffffff8006705000->0xffffff8006717fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[52C6EB14-CA4E-3209-BDD3-60092E16E6A4]@0xffffff8007c70000->0xffffff8007c81fff

Process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
20G1020

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Sun Nov  6 23:17:00 PST 2022; root:xnu-7195.141.46~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 68CA2B75-6148-38BC-BC33-38E18B20A8B1
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000004e00000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8005000000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000004e10000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8005010000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8004f00000
System model name: iMac15,1 (Mac-42FD25EABCABB274)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 4085337513289
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x000003b731175fa5
  Sleep   : 0x000003b4404833ba 0x0000000044148cad 0x000003a5ac0e273d
  Wake    : 0x000003b45a355d3d 0x0000000043844c6e 0x000003b459897ab6
last started kext at 4010420283161: >!UAudio    405.39 (addr 0xffffff7f9fbb5000, size 315392)
last stopped kext at 205833041203: >!ABacklightExpert   1.1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9e57d000, size 8192)
loaded kexts:
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   122.1
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@fsplaceholder  1.14.0
@fileutil   20.036.15
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    4.0.6
>!AMikeyHIDDriver   131
>!AHDA  283.15
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    4.0.6
>!AMikeyDriver  283.15
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.0.6
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.3.6
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.3.6
>pmtelemetry    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
|IO!BSerialManager  8.0.5d7
@kext.AMD7000!C 4.0.6
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  1
>eficheck   1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!A!IHD5000Graphics 16.0.5
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!ALPC  3.1
>!A!IFramebufferAzul    16.0.5
>!ARAID 5.1.0
|IO!BUSBDFU 8.0.5d7
|SCSITaskUserClient 436.140.1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   556.100.12
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1677.141.3
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  11.0.0
>!ASDXC 1.9.0
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AAHCIPort 346.100.2
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    311
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!UAudio    405.39
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@kext.AMDRadeonX4030HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  4.0.6
>!AGraphicsControl  6.3.6
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOAVB!F    940.4
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.AMDSupport    4.0.6
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    985.2
@!AGPUWrangler  6.3.6
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
|IONDRVSupport  585.2
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IOAudio!F  300.6.1
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOAccelerator!F2   442.9
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.3.6
|IOGraphics!F   585.2
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   5.0.3
>!AThunderboltPCIUpAdapter  4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   8.0.5d7
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 8.0.5d7
|IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.5d7
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  290.8.1
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AXsanScheme   3
|IOAHCIBlock!S  332
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>corecapture    1.0.4
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
|IOAHCI!F   294.100.1
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$!AImage4   3.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   985.2
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 8.0.5d7
|IOReport!F 47
|IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.5d7
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  511.141.1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.140.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.140.1
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.140.1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 11.1
@kec.Libm   1
```

Comment: 2014 iMacs used a mass storage device Apple called a *Fusion Drive*. As I learned from [my recent experience](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/446755/imac-mojave-suddenly-became-extremely-slow-on-login), when they go bad, they can go bad very quickly. **IF** it's your Fusion Drive, your options are limited (warning: [don't even *consider* this one](https://beetstech.com/store)). Hopefully, you have a recent TimeMachine backup. The IFIXIT website may have some useful repair info.